# How to get post categories from an object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Im trying to filter posts by categories from this array

```
Array [
  Object {
    "category": 1,
    "content": "For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.

[Link1](https://cso-web.herokuapp.com)",
    "content_preview": null,
    "coverImageSubtitle": null,
    "coverImageTitle": null,
    "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "custom_link": null,
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 1,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [],
    "pages": Array [
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:19:15.101Z",
        "id": 18,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Member Listing",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "member-listing",
        "template": "member-listing",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-28T09:29:56.383Z",
      },
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:28.500Z",
        "id": 22,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Evaluation Process / AL",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "evaluation-process",
        "template": "join-now",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:29.331Z",
      },
    ],
    "post_categories": Array [
      Object {
        "created_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:36.949Z",
        "id": 1,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Lajmet",
        "published_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:45.222Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:46.179Z",
      },
    ],
    "published_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "slider": Array [
      Object {
        "fixed": null,
        "id": 6,
        "image": Array [
          Object {
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.259Z",
            "ext": ".svg",
            "formats": null,
            "hash": "feature_image_297dbc6cd8",
            "height": 450,
            "id": 11,
            "mime": "image/svg+xml",
            "name": "feature-image.svg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "size": 54.94,
            "updated_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.522Z",
            "url": "/uploads/feature_image_297dbc6cd8.svg",
            "width": 600,
          },
        ],
        "parallax": null,
      },
    ],
    "sort": null,
    "subTitle": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "title": "Our Vision, Mission and Guiding Principles",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T09:27:39.155Z",
  },
  Object {
    "category": null,
    "content": "It is a quick and easy way for self-evaluating an organization in relation to the Global Standard for CSO Accountability, aiming at identifying strengths and areas for improvement.

<img src=\"/uploads/logo_2_319de9613c.jpeg\" style=\"width: 100px; height: 150px\" />

Legacy giving requires thought, lots of time and technical skills. So how do you make it as easy as possible for your donors to consider pledging a gift in a will? What decision science nudges can you use to help them along the decision-making process?

In this session you will learn the fundamentals of decision science, how people make decisions and which nudges you can use in your gifts in wills marketing to transform your appeals and secure pledges.

Learning Outcomes

1) Understand how designing legacy marketing differs from other fundraising materials
2) Learn how to leverage decision science nudges to inspire donors to consider leaving a gift in a will
3) How to write impactful legacy marketing",
    "content_preview": null,
    "coverImageSubtitle": null,
    "coverImageTitle": null,
    "created_at": "2021-05-25T21:21:03.979Z",
    "custom_link": null,
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 8,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [],
    "pages": Array [],
    "post_categories": Array [],
    "published_at": "2021-05-25T21:22:12.934Z",
    "slider": Array [],
    "sort": null,
    "subTitle": "Përparimi i karrierës suaj në një botë post pandemike",
    "thumbnail": null,
    "title": "Publikim CSO",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-25T21:22:13.300Z",
  },
  Object {
    "category": 2,
    "content": "For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.
For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.


- [CSO Report 2020-2021](/)
- [CSO Report 2020-2021](/)",
    "content_preview": null,
    "coverImageSubtitle": "adfasdf asdf asdf asdfsdf asdf ahsfahs dfhsdhha hhhahsd fhasd fhas dfhsahdf ahsdf ashdf hasdhf has dfh asdfhashdf. h sda fashdf hasd fhashd f ashdf hashdf ",
    "coverImageTitle": "Learn everything About CSO",
    "created_at": "2021-05-15T08:55:42.292Z",
    "custom_link": null,
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 2,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [],
    "pages": Array [],
    "post_categories": Array [],
    "published_at": "2021-05-15T08:55:42.292Z",
    "slider": Array [
      Object {
        "fixed": true,
        "id": 7,
        "image": Array [
          Object {
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.259Z",
            "ext": ".svg",
            "formats": null,
            "hash": "feature_image_297dbc6cd8",
            "height": 450,
            "id": 11,
            "mime": "image/svg+xml",
            "name": "feature-image.svg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "size": 54.94,
            "updated_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.522Z",
            "url": "/uploads/feature_image_297dbc6cd8.svg",
            "width": 600,
          },
        ],
        "parallax": null,
      },
    ],
    "sort": null,
    "subTitle": "subtitle goes here",
    "thumbnail": null,
    "title": "Our Vision, Mission and Guiding Principles",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T09:27:13.855Z",
  },
  Object {
    "category": null,
    "content": "",
    "content_preview": "A jeni gati për t`u bërë anëtar i Kodit? <br/>
Testoni Standardet aktuale të organizatës tuaj [këtu](/evaluation).",
    "coverImageSubtitle": null,
    "coverImageTitle": null,
    "created_at": "2021-07-30T15:37:09.909Z",
    "custom_link": "/join-now",
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 58,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [
      Object {
        "id": 61,
        "locale": "en",
        "published_at": "2021-09-06T08:12:34.668Z",
      },
    ],
    "pages": Array [
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": 2,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T13:17:54.278Z",
        "id": 10,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Rreth Kodit",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": true,
        "slug": "about",
        "template": "about",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-28T09:43:03.711Z",
      },
    ],
    "post_categories": Array [],
    "published_at": "2021-07-30T15:37:25.717Z",
    "slider": Array [
      Object {
        "fixed": false,
        "id": 99,
        "image": Array [
          Object {
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "created_at": "2021-06-22T11:21:15.147Z",
            "ext": ".1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
            "formats": Object {
              "large": Object {
                "ext": ".1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                "hash": "large_photo_1524178232363_1fb2b075b655_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxwa_G90by1w_Y_Wdlf_Hx8f_G_Vuf_DB_8f_Hx8_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_df5889d144",
                "height": 667,
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "name": "large_https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524178232363-1fb2b075b655?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                "path": null,
                "size": 93.66,
                "url": "/uploads/large_photo_1524178232363_1fb2b075b655_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxwa_G90by1w_Y_Wdlf_Hx8f_G_Vuf_DB_8f_Hx8_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_df5889d144.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                "width": 1000,
              },
              "medium": Object {
                "ext": ".1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                "hash": "medium_photo_1524178232363_1fb2b075b655_ixid_Mnwx_Mj_A3f_DB_8_M_Hxwa_G90by1w_Y_Wdlf_Hx8f_G_Vuf_DB_8f_Hx8_and_ixlib_rb_1_2_df5889d144",
                "height": 500,
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "name": "medium_https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524178232363-1fb2b075b655?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
                "path": null,
                "size": 59.18,
                "url": "/uploads/medium_photo_1524178232...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)
```

How can i go inside post_categories that i haven't figured out.
Here is the code I've done so far :

```
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  const filteredResults = useMemo(() => results.filter(result => category === null || result.post_categories[0].id === category), [results, category]);
  const toggleFilter = cat => {
    setCategory(c => cat === c ? null : cat);
    setResults(results)
  }
```

This shows an undefined is not an object error for result.post_categories[0].id
How can i access that id, inside post_categories so i can filter the results afterwards?
Right now in front page it shows all the posts. After a button is clicked the toggleFilter function is triggered and it should show only the posts with that category.

From the first array after aplying the filter the desired output  should go to this array :

```
Array [
  Object {
    "category": 1,
    "content": "For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.

[Link1](https://cso-web.herokuapp.com)",
    "content_preview": null,
    "coverImageSubtitle": null,
    "coverImageTitle": null,
    "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "custom_link": null,
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 1,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [],
    "pages": Array [
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:19:15.101Z",
        "id": 18,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Member Listing",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "member-listing",
        "template": "member-listing",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-28T09:29:56.383Z",
      },
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:28.500Z",
        "id": 22,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Evaluation Process / AL",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "evaluation-process",
        "template": "join-now",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:29.331Z",
      },
    ],
    "post_categories": Array [
      Object {
        "created_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:36.949Z",
        "id": 1,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Lajmet",
        "published_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:45.222Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:46.179Z",
      },
    ],
    "published_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "slider": Array [
      Object {
        "fixed": null,
        "id": 6,
        "image": Array [
          Object {
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.259Z",
            "ext": ".svg",
            "formats": null,
            "hash": "feature_image_297dbc6cd8",
            "height": 450,
            "id": 11,
            "mime": "image/svg+xml",
            "name": "feature-image.svg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "size": 54.94,
            "updated_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.522Z",
            "url": "/uploads/feature_image_297dbc6cd8.svg",
            "width": 600,
          },
        ],
        "parallax": null,
      },
    ],
    "sort": null,
    "subTitle": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "title": "Our Vision, Mission and Guiding Principles",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T09:27:39.155Z",
  },
 Object {
    "category": 2,
    "content": "test",
    "content_preview": null,
    "coverImageSubtitle": null,
    "coverImageTitle": null,
    "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "custom_link": null,
    "gallery": Array [],
    "id": 1,
    "isDeleted": null,
    "locale": "sq",
    "localizations": Array [],
    "pages": Array [
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:19:15.101Z",
        "id": 18,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Member Listing",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "member-listing",
        "template": "member-listing",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-28T09:29:56.383Z",
      },
      Object {
        "commitments": null,
        "content_sub_menu": null,
        "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:28.500Z",
        "id": 22,
        "isActive": true,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Evaluation Process / AL",
        "showOnFooterMenu": null,
        "showOnMainMenu": null,
        "slug": "evaluation-process",
        "template": "join-now",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:29.331Z",
      },
    ],
    "post_categories": Array [
      Object {
        "created_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:36.949Z",
        "id": 1,
        "locale": "sq",
        "name": "Lajmet",
        "published_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:45.222Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:46.179Z",
      },
    ],
    "published_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
    "slider": Array [
      Object {
        "fixed": null,
        "id": 6,
        "image": Array [
          Object {
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.259Z",
            "ext": ".svg",
            "formats": null,
            "hash": "feature_image_297dbc6cd8",
            "height": 450,
            "id": 11,
            "mime": "image/svg+xml",
            "name": "feature-image.svg",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "size": 54.94,
            "updated_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.522Z",
            "url": "/uploads/feature_image_297dbc6cd8.svg",
            "width": 600,
          },
        ],
        "parallax": null,
      },
    ],
    "sort": null,
    "subTitle": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "title": "Our Vision, Mission and Guiding Principles",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T09:27:39.155Z",
  },
```

Here is the button that should filter the results :

```
<Button shadowless style={styles.buttonStyle} onPress={() => { toggleFilter(1) }} >
```

---

Comment: Can u add the actual array and an example of the desired output?

Comment: That is the actual array that comes from an api endpoint. I will add the desired output, check the edited version

Comment: @NeelDsouza can u check it now please

Comment: By desired output I meant, the filtered array that you want as a result. So that we can get more understanding of your problem. We wont understand by UI images.

Comment: I added it @NeelDsouza but the output should be the array returning only those posts with that category id. Am i clear enough, my English isn't that good, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the undefined error because for few of the cases the `post_categories` array is empty and if u try accessing the 0th element it will throw an error. So add a null check for the array length and for id something like below

```js
const arr = [
    {
      "category": 1,
      "content": "For 50 years, AFP has been the standard-bearer for professionalism in fundraising. Learn more about AFP, its activities and people, and how you can be involved.",
      "content_preview": null,
      "coverImageSubtitle": null,
      "coverImageTitle": null,
      "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
      "custom_link": null,
      "gallery": [],
      "id": 1,
      "isDeleted": null,
      "locale": "sq",
      "localizations": [],
      "pages": [
        {
          "commitments": null,
          "content_sub_menu": null,
          "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:19:15.101Z",
          "id": 18,
          "isActive": true,
          "locale": "sq",
          "name": "Member Listing",
          "showOnFooterMenu": null,
          "showOnMainMenu": null,
          "slug": "member-listing",
          "template": "member-listing",
          "updated_at": "2021-09-28T09:29:56.383Z",
        },
        {
          "commitments": null,
          "content_sub_menu": null,
          "created_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:28.500Z",
          "id": 22,
          "isActive": true,
          "locale": "sq",
          "name": "Evaluation Process / AL",
          "showOnFooterMenu": null,
          "showOnMainMenu": null,
          "slug": "evaluation-process",
          "template": "join-now",
          "updated_at": "2021-05-19T21:33:29.331Z",
        },
      ],
      "post_categories": [
        {
          "created_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:36.949Z",
          "id": 1,
          "locale": "sq",
          "name": "Lajmet",
          "published_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:45.222Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:46.179Z",
        },
        {
          "created_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:36.949Z",
          "id": 2,
          "locale": "sq",
          "name": "Lajmet",
          "published_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:45.222Z",
          "updated_at": "2021-05-20T15:54:46.179Z",
        },
      ],
      "published_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:17.260Z",
      "slider": [
        {
          "fixed": null,
          "id": 6,
          "image": [
            {
              "alternativeText": "",
              "caption": "",
              "created_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.259Z",
              "ext": ".svg",
              "formats": null,
              "hash": "feature_image_297dbc6cd8",
              "height": 450,
              "id": 11,
              "mime": "image/svg+xml",
              "name": "feature-image.svg",
              "previewUrl": null,
              "provider": "local",
              "provider_metadata": null,
              "size": 54.94,
              "updated_at": "2021-05-13T18:34:10.522Z",
              "url": "/uploads/feature_image_297dbc6cd8.svg",
              "width": 600,
            },
          ],
          "parallax": null,
        },
      ],
      "sort": null,
      "subTitle": null,
      "thumbnail": null,
      "title": "Our Vision, Mission and Guiding Principles",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-22T09:27:39.155Z",
    }]

  console.log(arr.filter(el => el.post_categories.length > 0 && el.id === el.post_categories[0]?.id))
  // console.log(arr.map(el => ({...el, post_categories: el.post_categories.filter(post => post.id === el.category)})))
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not being clear. What i want to do is filter the array of posts based on post_categories, disregard the category thats in the first line in array that isnt needed. The array structure is kinda like this ` arr [
post1 :{
 id: 1
content: 'test'
post_categories{
 id : 1
}
},
post2 :{
 id: 2
content: 'test'
post_categories:{
 id : 2
}
}
]
`
Now i just want post1 one for example, how can i filter that

Comment: Still bit confusing. `post_categories` is again an array. How can we check that in posts? Do you mean `post_categories[0].id` should be present in posts and filter that?

Comment: Yeah the `post_categories` is an array inside an array that is  post1 or post2 for example. Thats how the structure of the api endpoint is. Yes im trying to navigate in that array like this `post_categories[0].id` but it shows an undefined error when i do that